# Relationship ordered by column?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I want my publications relationship ordered by the 'ordering' column.
This is what I've come up with so far:

```
class Book extends Model
{
     public $hasMany = [
         'publications' => ['Codalia\Bookend\Models\Publication']
     ];
  ...
}

class Publication extends Model
{
     public $belongsTo = [
         'book' => ['Codalia\Bookend\Models\Book']
     ];
  ...
}

$book = Book::with(['publications' => function ($q){
    $q->orderBy('ordering');
}])->where('id', $id)->get();

$book->publications;
```

but I get an error:

> Property [publications] does not exist on this collection instance.

Why do I retrieve a collection and not a Book object ?

Comment: Never seen relationships declared like that, do you have any source where you got that from?

Comment: It's the classic way of declaring relationships in a model. What's wrong with it ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, never seen it, I was just always using "the method" type declaration they use in the documentation. Learned something today ;)

Comment: Ok. You can find some examples here: https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->get();` is gonna return a collection of many. What you are looking for is `->first();`

```
$book = Book::with(['publications' => function ($q){
    $q->orderBy('ordering');
}])->where('id', $id)->first(); // here

$book->publications;
```